# Speech Recognition with AVAudioEngine Blocks Sound After Recording

Tags: ios, swift, audio, swift3, speech-recognition

I am trying to run the Apple *SpeakToMe: Using Speech Recognition with AVAudioEngine* sample from [their website here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SpeakToMe/Listings/SpeakToMe_ViewController_swift.html). My problem is that when you stop the AVAudioEngine and SpeechRecognizer you can no longer use system sounds.

**How do you release the AVAudioEngine and SpeechRecognizer so that sounds will work again after recording stops?**

To duplicate this:

- download the sample code
- add a UITextField to the storyboard.
- run the project and type into the text field (you'll notice you can hear your typing event sounds).
- Then start recording and stop recording
- Type into the text field again **(Now there will be no sound)**

**UPDATE**

This only happens on a real device - not on the simulator.

Answer (score 6):

After hours of debugging I came across the un-released object causing issues. In their sample code they do not release the AVAudioSession. This causes the sound channels to be blocked.

The fix is to make the AVAudioSession a property:

```
private var audioSession : AVAudioSession?
```

And then set `audioSession.active` to false when stopping the recording:

```
if let audioSession = audioSession {
    do {
        try audioSession.setActive(false, with: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
    } catch {
        // handle error
    }
}
```